# How to Pass ActiveRecord Objects as Parameters to Helper Methods in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, helpermethods

Many helper methods, such as redirect_to, link_to, and url_for, can take an ActiveRecord object as a parameter instead of a hash that specifies the controller and action.  I've seen the parameter passed different ways in different documentation.  It sometimes gets passed as a symbol, sometimes as an instance variable, and sometimes as a local variable.

I'm confused about how the different parameter styles get expanded to return urls.  I know that following REST conventions should create a url constructed of a controller and action but am unsure when Rails needs a specific parameter style to construct that url.  Please help me understand the use cases for passing the ActiveRecord object as a symbol, an instance variable, or a local variable.  Are there different requirements based on the method call?  Or are there underlying differences in url construction?

Here are some examples:

From the API docs:

```
link_to "Profile", @profile  
redirect_to post  
<%= url_for(@workshop) %>  
<%= form_for :person do |f| %> (this is described as the “generic #form_for”)
```

From the Ruby on Rails Guides:

```
<%= link_to 'New book', new_book_path %>  
redirect_to(@book)  
form_for(@article)
```

From the Rails 3 Way:

```
'link_to' "Help", help_widgets_path, :popup => 1  
redirect_to post  
url_for(timesheets_path)  
form_for offer do |f|
```

Note: Upon further research, it seems that form_for is able to accept a local variable in the case where the calling view template passes a :locals hash as a parameter.  The keys are the locals that can be used in the partial and the values are the instance variables from the template. Is that the correct understanding?

Comment: can you add an example of "ActiveRecord object as a symbol" --- not sure what you mean with that. The rest I can answer when that's clear.

Comment: Hi Jesse, thanks for your help.  I just edited the post with samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can pass objects to link_to and url_for
- You can also pass an object to a path helper
- Both `@post` and `post` are objects. @post is an instance variable, and post is either a local variable or a method that will return a post

The only "weird" one is the `form_for :post` variety. This is old school Rails syntax, and will change this to the `form_for @post` syntax under the hood.

Comment: Sorry, can you define what you mean by path helper?  How are path helpers different from link_to and url_for?  Also, should I just safely assume that there's never a need to use the "symbol as a stand-in for an instance variable" style and instead always just pass the instance variable?

Comment: Yes, never use the symbol. path helpers are `edit_post_path(@post)` or `posts_path`

Comment: Oh got it--you meant the named route helpers suffixed with either _path or _url.  (Duh).  Thanks!